# Pointer to object in another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am retrieving data via SignalR and keeping the most recent data returned in a dictionary that exists in my WebServices class.

I'd like to be able to have a pointer to this dictionary and be able to use the data in many other classes / viewcontrollers.

I want to avoid creating an instance of my WebServices class everywhere I use the data.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to share data like this is to put it in your app delegate class.

Just create the dictionary in your appDelegate, and whenever you need to access it just retrieve it with:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
NSDictionary *myDictionary = appDelegate.myDictionary;

// Do whatever you want with myDictionary
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your WebServices class a singleton. This sort of app-wide data is a good use-case for a singleton.

Comment: Until you discover your app needs to handle two or more possible sets of data instead of just one. This is why using a singleton for app-wide data is a bad idea. Requirements change and when you have to refactor an entire app because you unwisely chose to use a singleton, it's no fun.

Comment: Certainly you would need to do some analysis of the requirements and think about possible **future** requirements before making your decision. Using a data container singleton is certainly better than just jamming a dictionary into the app delegate as suggested in the other answer.